# Check if an item is set in an array and test for equality

Tags: php, function, built-in

I was reading somewhere (possibly here on SO) that there is a built-in PHP function that is shorthand for checking if an item in an array is set and then testing it for equality. I realize that I can easily recreate this with the following snippet, but I was just wondering if there *is* a built-in way to do this. There's no need to reinvent the wheel, but if this isn't a reinvention, I suppose this is the answer.

```
<?php
    function item_equality(&$array, $key, $operand) {
        return isset($array[$key]) && $array[$key] == $operand;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, it's not a function I was looking for, it is an operator. It is the [error control operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php). With you can use something such as the following.

```
<?php
    if (@$array[$key] == $operand) {
        // do stuff
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this matches exactly what you have in mind, but you can get similar functionality using:

```
<?php
 if (array_search($operand, $array) == $key) {
   ....
 }
```

I'd be wary of using @ - it can potentially hide other problems.

Comment: If there is more than one of the same value, this may fail. It is also pretty slow for large arrays. It also may not work if `FALSE` is used as a key.

Comment: All true, it depends on the situation as to what will work. I believe the code you posted in your question is a better solution than using @, but I am not a fan of the operator.